# Not able to compile this error shows CANNOT SET HEADERS AFTER THEY ARE SENT TO CLIENT

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
app. get('/GitHub', function( request , res) {
    constant parameters = {}
     res. status(200).render('GitHub. pug', parameters)// This is loading the template for taking input`
    constant topic=req. body. top;//this takes input from the first one for searching and where clause.
      db. query("SELECT * from GitHub where topic=?",[topic],function(err, rows, fields){
        if(err) throw err
      res. render('users',{title: 'Details', items: rows})// This is displaying database table.   

    })
})
```

this shows error due to multiple render calls in single route. I want to show the mysql data after getting the input from the form.

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you may only call `.status()` and `.render()` once in each request: they send your results to your user's browser.  Your second `.render()` tries to set some http headers (maybe the content-type?) after the results are sent, and fails because the first calls sent them already.

Gather your parameters *and* your results into a *single* object, then call `.render()` with that object.

And, the first parameter to `render()` is a file name. Yours `Github. pug` has a space in it. That is probably not correct.

Comment: Well, it's not like `constant topic` is correct either...